How can I create a tree diagram from two columns in R that are interconnected?
I have columns arranged like the below:
Product: Charge:
P1       C1
P1       C2
P2       C1
P2       C3
P3       C2

I need to show a tree diagram that sets the first product, P1 and then shows all the charges attached to that (p1 - c1 and p1 to c2) and then the next quadrant shows the products that are attached to those charges c1 and c2. Then the next quadrant shows the charges attached to those products and so on and so on until there are no more relations to add.
FromDataFrameNetwork does not work as it says cannot find root name. Network is not a tree. Please help.
See above explanation.

How do I create those from the data I have? Cannot do it manually as the data sets can get very large

If your data a tibble (as opposed to a data frame)?

No it's a dataframe. List of connecting products and charges.

Well, the function won't let you have multiple roots for the first column. As it looks, you have 3. You can only have one root.

Can I set the root?

That would mean changing the data. For example, If all values of the first column were "P1" then the function would work. Look at the acme data as an example.

That example is good but I think the main issue is I need the connections to go both way. So one path would be P1 - C1 - P2 for example.

You can use igraph like below
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE)
dfout <- setNames(
  do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(
      all_shortest_paths(g,
        from = "P1",
        to = V(g)[degree(g) == 1]
      )$vpath,
      \(x) {
        as.data.frame(embed(names(x), 2)[, 2:1])
      }
    )
  ),
  c("from", "to")
)

and you will obtain
> dfout
  from to
1   P1 C2
2   C2 P3
3   P1 C1
4   C1 P2
5   P2 C3

and its visualization
dfout %>%
  graph_from_data_frame() %>%
  plot(layout = layout_as_tree)



If you want tree diagram
> library(data.tree)

> FromDataFrameNetwork(dfout)
       levelName
1 P1
2  ¦--C2
3  ¦   °--P3
4  °--C1
5      °--P2
6          °--C3


Thank you! Can I create a tree diagram from that with P1 as the root node?

Thank you! How do I use this tree structure to create a dataframe with the levels separate?

@user26671382 see update at the bottom
